# responsive design- position fixed and fullscreen image

Tags: jquery, css, responsive-design

I have a little problem with a responsive design that I made for a customer.
I have a background div with position fixed that contain an img.
On the smartphone in the portrait visualization I set the *height* of the img to `100%` and the *width* to `auto`.
In this way the image cover the entire height of the window and don't distort his width.

The problem is that work on ios smartphone and on web (I've tried on emulators like ipadpeek.com and Riplle for chrome), but on my galaxy 3 the image still covers the entire height of the window but it distorts it horizontaly:

**HTML**:

```
<div id="bg_container">
    <img src="images/home-1.jpg" />
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```css
@media only screen and (min-width : 321px) and (max-width : 360px) {
    #bg_container {
        position:fixed;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        z-index:0;
        overflow:hidden;
    }
    #bg_container img {
        height:100%;
        width:auto;
        position:relative;
    }
}
```

[**Link test page**](http://www.jeanclaudechiementin.com/dinomusa/about.html)

Comment: You shouldn't trust sites like ipadpeek.com to show you what an actual ipad will render your site like. All they are doing is showing you your site at the SIZE of an ipad screen. It's still using the rendering engine of whatever browser you are using to actually render the page.

Comment: I know that, but the problem is on a physic galaxy3 and i have tested on an iphone 4 and 3 and an ipad3 and 2... on the ios the width:auto run correctly and don't distort the image, on the galaxy no...

Comment: I have found a jquery that can resolve the problem, but i think it's not the must correct way...I think there's can be a pure Css way:

Comment: var $scrollingDiv = $("#bg-nivo-slider");
  
    $(window).scroll(function(){   
 $scrollingDiv
 .stop()
 .animate({"marginTop": ($(window).scrollTop() + 0) + "px"}, 0);   
    });

Comment: It works but i think is not the best way, especially for the mobile devices, because he have to calculate the margin-top on every little scrolling of the page... i think it can be to loud and slow.

What do you think about?

Comment: link page with jquery:
http://www.jeanclaudechiementin.com/dinomusa/news.html

link page without jquery:
http://www.jeanclaudechiementin.com/dinomusa/news.html

Comment: unfortunaly i can't answer on my own ask until 8 hours so i've posted here like a comment

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your width's to max-width: this is a new property that works Magic!!

Also, For testing your design, Google Chrome Responsive Mobile View as I believe this uses the proper engine for displaying your work

Comment: Google Chrome Responsive Mobile View? Is it the Ripple extension?? If yes i have tested with it but on the computer work on the galaxy mobile no...

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved by changing the slider on the mobile, also because the nivo slider is too loud with rain block transition for the mobile devices...
I've tried also with the max-width but nothing change...